# Why unordered JSON values?

Tags: python, json

I've got the next code on python that convert two lists to json:

```
JSONRules = json.dumps(
    [{'RuleAction':action, 'RuleName':name} for action, name in zip(RulesAction, RulesName)]
)
```

But the output it's totally random, why?

out[1]:

```
[{"RuleAction": "0", "RuleName": "Policy4"}, {"RuleAction": "0", "RuleName": "Policy5"}]
```

out[2]:

```
[{"RuleName": "Policy4", "RuleAction": "0"}, {"RuleName": "Policy5", "RuleAction": "0"}]
```

Comment: What Python version are you using? In Python2 dictionaries aren't ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python dict was `unordered` before Python 3.7. You could use `sort_keys=True` flag from `json.dumps()`. More about [json encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries aren't ordered.

Add `sort_keys=True` to the `json.dumps()` invocation to always sort object keys in the JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

Because json in python is parsed as dictionary and normal dictionary in python is unordered if you want to be ordered you have use ordered dict

```
from collections import OrderedDict

OrderedDict({"a":1})
```

Comment: Note that since Python 3.7, dict are always sorted, it's part of the language's specs : https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html

Comment: Thanks I didn't knew about that